# Is it possible to get ALL WebElements on a web page using WebDriver

Tags: java, webdriver

Something like:

```
WebElement inputs =  driver.findElement(By.tagName("input"));
```

or

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElementsBy(By.tagName("a"));
```

What i wanted was a name/value pair like structure which gives me tagName vs Quantity
My Objective is to have a list of these Elements and make a Series of tests associated with them, since different users would have their own unique set of these Elements per page.
I hope i got my message across.

Comment: What about `findElements(By.cssSelector("*"))`?

Comment: Or driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*"));

Comment: Either of the two answers should work, but why do you need to do this? It will end up being slow and incredibly inefficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*"));
```

or

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("*"));
```

Then just sort the list as needed using getTagName or other functions.

Comment: i get:
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on XP (6fbfb5ba-3ef1-44a4-8778-5238fb5dd5b0)] -> tag name: html]] -> xpath: *]
[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on XP (6fbfb5ba-3ef1-44a4-8778-5238fb5dd5b0)] -> tag name: html]] -> xpath: *]

Comment: I've updated with the answers given by Philipp Reichart and JacekM.  Your only problem might be if you are dealing with frames/iframes then you will have to iterate through them if you need the information found inside.

Comment: Hi James, I too getting the same answer as mentioned above by Kamal. Please let me know whether the above solution works for you?

Comment: @Kamal, Please let me know if you have any other solution to address your question.

Answer (score 1):

This [repo](https://github.com/pgrandje) looks promising, as page object generation tool

look at [Paul Grandjean Prototype Tool for Configurable Selenium Code Generation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N833cTfL6Sg)

https://github.com/pgrandje/pohelper2